# Jgit:Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index

Tags: java, git, jgit

i have created a directory in E named it gitrepo full path is (E:\gitrepo) after then i have cloned a repository in it with the following code

```
Git git=Git.cloneRepository()
                .setURI("samplelink.git")
                .setDirectory(new File("/E:/gitrepo"))
                .call();
```

then i opened a repository using this code

```
public Repository openRepository() throws IOException {
    FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();

    Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File("/E:/gitrepo"))
            .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
            .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
            .build();
     log.info("Repository directory is {}", repository.getDirectory());

    return repository;
}
```

everything worked fine till here
then i tried to add a file in this local repository

```
Repository repo = openRepository();
            Git git = new Git(repo);
            File myfile = new File(repo.getDirectory()/*.getParent()*/, "testfile");
            if (!myfile.createNewFile()) {
                throw new IOException("Could not create file " + myfile);
            }
            log.info("file created at{}", myfile.getPath());
            git.add().addFilepattern("testfile").call();
```

Then i got exception on this line

```
git.add().addFilepattern("testfile").call();
```

here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoWorkTreeException: Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.getIndexFile(Repository.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.lockDirCache(Repository.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:149)
    at com.km.GitAddFile.addFile(GitAddFile.java:26)
```

although the file code created in `E:\gitrepo`
i have checked  gitrepo is non-bare-repository by this command

```
/e/gitrepo (master)
$ git rev-parse --is-bare-repository
```

and its returning `false`

please help how can i resolve this exception

Comment: Are you sure that `repo` points to the same repository as `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository`? What does `ls` reveal when executed in `/e/gitrepo`? What does `repo.getDirectory()` point to?

Comment: yes the repo points to /e/gitrepo where i am running git rev-parse --is-bare-repository and ls revels threee files README.md  sample.txt  testfile in /e/gitrepo

Comment: log.info("Repository directory is {}", repository.getDirectory()); outputs ->NFO: Repository directory is E:\gitrepo

Comment: The usage of `FileRepositoryBuilder` is incorrect, you're pointing it to `gitrepo`, while the repository meta directory is `gitrepo/.git`. You should replace this usage by `Git.open(new File("/E:/gitrepo"))`.

Comment: it worked :) you can post this as answerso it may help others

Comment: Glad that it helps you! I added it to the answer @user9452933.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Opening a Git repository using `FileRepositoryBuilder` is tricky. This is an internal class. Its method `setGitDir(File)` defines the location of the repository metadata (the `.git` folder). In other words, it is used to construct a Git bare repository. You can prove it by calling the `Repository#isBare()`:

```
Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File("/E:/gitrepo"))
        .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
        .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
        .build();
repository.isBare(); // returns true
```

You should replace this usage by `Git#open(File)`:

```
try (Git git = Git.open(new File("/E:/gitrepo"))) {
    // Do sth ...
}
```

Comment: Default thought would be to call the Git constructor you need a repository, and then in the documentation to construct a repository it shows the OP approach. https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Repository

Yet no mention of Git.open in the documentation.  Kind of confusing.  Your post saved me a ton of time, thanks!